# IVs: would this rainfall specification cut it?

Tags: causality, instrumental-variables, 2sls, research-design

I need feedback to check whether rainfall is an appropriate instrumental variable. Before you boo me out, hear what I have to say.

There are two countries: A and B. A and B are 2000 miles apart.

My hypothesis is that industrial activity in country A is an important source of mortality for its own citizens. I worry that endogeneity would be an issue if I would regress mortality on industrial activity. I could use rainfall in country A as an instrumental variable. After all, the factories rely on agricultural inputs from country A. We all know this can be problematic since the exclusion restriction does not hold out: rainfall in country A probably affects mortality in many different ways.

What if I used rainfall in country B? The industries in country A also rely on agricultural inputs that are only grown in country B. The first stage equation uses rainfall in country B to predict industrial activity in country A. The second stage uses predicted industrial activity to predict mortality.

I think that my exclusion restriction claim is much stronger—even if I use an infamous IV.

Comment: Economics Stack Exchange might be another good place for the question, but please only post on a single Stach Exchange site at once (i.e. do not cross post).

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably need more context knowledge for a more comprehensive answer, but let me try to give a brief evaluation of using rainfall in $B$ as IV for industrial activity $\to$ mortality in $A$ based off what you wrote:

**Exogeneity:**
Sounds fair enough, probably a big reason why rainfall is so popular.

**Exclusion Restriction**:
I could see this one if the countries really are that far apart (not sure what time period). However, you clearly state that the industry of $A$ relies on inputs from $B$. So it seems very likely to me that the countries are linked in other ways, too. For example, a lack of rainfall in country $B$ would, in your model, probably reduce the industrial output of $B$ more so than that of $A$, which might lead the industry in $A$ to make up for the shortfall and trade with $B$. In short, once you have economies that are linked over thousands of miles, I find it hard to believe that there aren't at least a few channels by which they could influence one another. Perhaps the most obvious one is actually food prices and exports which may affect mortality directly without industrial activity.

**Relevance**:
This one is related to the exclusion restriction. I'm happy to believe that it is relevant if the economies of the countries are linked, but if that is the case you might have problems with the exclusion restriction. That being said, if we're really talking about somewhat advanced economies, I'm not convinced the fluctuations of rainfall in another country thousands of miles away would really be that relevant.

In summary, I see what you're getting at and it's always hard to find something exogenous that's still relevant and passes the exclusion restriction. Given the information you provided, I personally wouldn't buy the rainfall as an instrument in this case for the reasons stated above.